# ffmpeg bitrate variating without reason

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, mp4, bitrate

I got a mp4 video.
I just want to split it in 4GB file parts using ffmpeg (to make it writeable on FAT32).

```
C:\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe -i "%NAME%.mp4" -n -t %LENGTH% -codec copy "%NAME%_1.mp4"
C:\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe -ss %LENGTH% -i "%NAME%.mp4" -n -codec copy "%NAME%_2.mp4"
```

- The original file's overall bitrate is 9450 Kbps.
- The first output's
  overall bitrate is 10.1 Mbps.
- The second output's overall bitrate is
  8727 Kbps.

I guess that the bitrate of the original video is variable and not equally distributed, is that right ?

How can I fix it (in a batch that would be great)? May I convert first the original video to constant bitrate?

Thanks for help guys !

Comment: Is the problem that the two parts don't land at less than 4GB every time?

Comment: Yes because I calculate the length of outputs based on bitrate. In the given example, the first output would be around 4,25GB.

Comment: Think about using the segmenter in ffmpeg. [ffmpeg segmenter documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) Changing the bitrate will require a re-encode. Why not just undershoot to 3GB?

Comment: I'm actually not confident in re-encode (afraid of quality loss).
So I'll undershoot, as you said. But I'm still looking for an answer if someone have one :)